# Reading inputs from TextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to read the input from 2 textfield from multiple TableViewCell, Looks like it only access input2 and append input2 twice to the inputRead array. How could I fix this? Many thanks

P/S: This is how I layout 2 TextFields in a cell: [input1] [input2]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

    customCell.input1.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input2.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input1.delegate = self
    customCell.input2.delegate = self

    return customCell
} 

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return textField.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)
    if let customCell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? 
    CustomCell {

        let string1 = String(customCell.input1.text!)
        let string2 = String(customCell.input2.text!)
        inputRead.append(input(string1, string2))
    }

}//end class

class CustomCell : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var input1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var input2: UITextField!
}
```

Comment: can't understand your point? can add example what is your input and output ?

Comment: What is  inputRead.append(input(string1, string2))?

Comment: @Nimesh inputRead is just an array of input object. That's where I append those 2 strings I read from TextFields.

Comment: @Alan in textFieldDidEndEditing  string1 & string2 get correct value ?

Comment: Yeah, but seems like it only accesses input2 and covert input2 to string2 twice.

Comment: inputRead.append(input(string1, string2)) you get correct value of string1 & string2 here??

Comment: Yes I did get them correct

Comment: inputRead.append(input(string1, string2)) What is input  ?

Comment: struct input{
    var str1:String
    var str2:String
}

Comment: `textFieldDidEndEditing` should be called multiple times as you are trying to edit both textfield, if you don't want inputRead to append multiple times then just create a property instead of array

Comment: How would you call `textFieldDidEndEditing` multiple times?

Comment: If `string1` and `string2` hold the correct values, the problem must be in the `input` struct. Indeed, `input(string1, string2)` should not work at all, it should be `input(str1:string1, str2:string2)` - so do you have a custom `init()` function?

Comment: Why you need textFieldDidEndEditing multiple times?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Nothing wrong with the struct. I have tested append function and it worked perfectly. The problem is that string2 is appended perfectly, but string1 is never accessed and therefore never appended. Somehow, textfield input2 is accessed twice from both line `let string1 = String(customCell.input1.text!)
        let string2 = String(customCell.input2.text!)` and therefore appended twice to the inputRead array.

Comment: I can only think of some strange IBOutlet connection problem from your XIB to the View. Maybe you have three `UITextField`s in the XIB (due to copy/paste), two of them overlapping, so one is invisible but connected to `label1`?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Could be the case. Thanks for helping